# SQL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE with metacharacters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The records I am querying for are kept in 2 different formats. Each person has at least 1 record of their email in the format John.Doe@abc.com. Some people have a second record in which their email is DoeJ@abc.com.

How can I query for the records in which the email is formatted like John.Doe@abc.com?

I attempted to do it with the following SQL Statement but I it returns an empty result:

```
Select * from email where regexp_like(emailaddress, '. (@)')
```

The end product will be used in a join with a few other Queries, so selecting distinct values is not an option here. The environment is an Oracle DB, and because this will be done through multiple joins, the more efficient it is the better. Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong, or other ways to accomplish this?

Thank you,
Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REGEXP_LIKE:

```
Select * from email where regexp_like(emailaddress, '\S*\.\S*\@\S*\.\S*')
```

Use "\S*" to match all non-whitespace characters

Or just a regular LIKE:

```
Select * from email where emailaddress LIKE '%.%@%.%'
```

Not sure what characters are included in the % placeholder in Oracle, so you should test it out.

The REGEXP one will give you tighter control over the pattern matching.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a ton

Comment: No prob bob :) .

Answer (score 0):

How about using `like`?

```
where emailaddress like '%.%@%'
```

The first format seems distinguished by having a period before the ampersand.

Comment: I did forget about that, and it does work. I am just a little worried if when I put it together, using like with all the '%' will give me an efficiency hit

Comment: @JoshuaAverbuch - The LIKE approach will be faster than regexp. It will still be slow. Anything to do with such text searches will be slow. If that is not ok, consider function based index, materialized view, or other solutions along those lines.